# How to avoid IndexError: list index out of range for previous or next line

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with lines, in order:

```
line 1 
line 2 
line 3
line 4 
line 5
```

Now for example, if `line 4` exist in the text file, I need to display the previous or next word relative to `line 4` in order: previous is `line 3` next is `line 5`

```
data = open('file.txt', "r")
searchlines = data.readlines()
for q_numb, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if ('line 4') in line:
        prev_line = searchlines[q_numb - 1]
        print ('"line 4" is found:',line, 'previous of "line 4" is:',prev_line)
        break
data.close()
```

How do I avoid `IndexError: list index out of range` if `[q_numb - 1]` or `[q_numb + 1]` comes to an non-existent line? Should I just tell it to do something else, maybe somehow predict it? But how do I do that, how do I know to do something else if `-` or `+1` comes to a non-existent line? (For example, read only the current line in this case).

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to identify zero. The value of zero turns out to be pretty consistent over time. And it shouldn't be too hard to find out the length of `searchlines`. If the index is going to be out of range, don't do that one.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to check if the index of the current line `i` is always more than 0 and less than the length of the file, so at any time there is always a previous line and the next one.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'line 3' in line and 0 < i < len(lines):
                print(lines[i - 1], line, lines[i + 1])
```

This will prints out the previous, the current and the next line for 'line 2', 'line 3' and 'line 4' and ignore 'line 1' and 'line 5' which do not have a previous and next line to print.

Also, use `with` as an idiomatic way to open a resource with implicit `close`.

Comment: so with this one I can avoid 0 and next too, can I do the same without def for just for plus

Comment: def is just to declare it a function. Of course you can do the same without it. I assume by "plus" you mean only check for the next line? If so you don't have to check if i is more than 0 and just check that it's less than len(lines).

Comment: can you show me please how to do it without def because on plus I have same error out of range, if I go this way: `data = open('D:\path\file.txt', "r")
searchlines = data.readlines() 
for q_numb, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if ('line 4') in line and 0 < q_numb < len(searchlines): `

Comment: @L_Oni Try the exact edited code. I ran it without problem.

Comment: well I've tried it guess exactly as you say: `with open('D:\path\file.txt', "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
    for q_numb, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if ('line 3') in line and 0 < q_numb < len(searchlines): 
            prev_line = searchlines[q_numb + 1]
            print(prev_line)` but same error out of range if last line in list...

Comment: I've tried and it worked. Check if your path to the file is correct and the file isn't empty.

Comment: no in file I have three lines: word 1 word 2 word 3, so word 3 is last one and if ask for word 3 next_line = searchlines[q_numb + 1] I got error

Comment: Make sure you did not declare `next_line = searchlines[q_numb + 1]` or `prev_line = searchlines[q_numb - 1]` outside of the `if` statement because it is what protects you from going outside of the index range. If you stick to the code there is no way you can get error index out of range no matter how many lines you got in file.txt

Comment: it is inside the `if 'line 3' in line and 0 < i < len(lines):` but then when I'm asking for next line it is inside `for l in searchlines:` which is inside first statement too, because if I have it  just after if 'line 3' in line and 0 < i < len(lines):` plus works, but I have only first character from next or previous word

Comment: ok now I did it exactly as you show, it works well, but I don't know why, sometime if I have as last line phrase "my name is", sometimes but not each time I have same error index out of range. its happens with any phrase or word but time after time, so how to avoid it now...maybe need some correction ? only thing help, how can I put some symbol like this one "_" under the last word in list with space? because if I put it once then new word comes over it, so this is solution for me I guess

Answer (score -1):

Use an `if` statement:

```
data = open('file.txt', "r")
searchlines = data.readlines()
lines_len = len(searchlines)
for q_numb, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if ('line 4') in line && 0 < q_numb < lines_len: #Here
        prev_line = searchlines[q_numb - 1]
        print ('"line 4" is found:',line, 'previous of "line 4" is:',prev_line)
        break
data.close()
```

Comment: well now I see first version also works very good what the differences `0 < q_numb < lines_len` and first one `0 < q_numb` in this case?

Comment: The second version checks to see whether `q_numb` is less than the length of `searchlines`, so that adding one to the index triggers no error.

Comment: yes  with minus  but with plus I have same error again